# Showing wait spinner while Exporting stuff to word

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, spin.js

I have an anchor tag which on click redirects to an action that exports one of my MVC Views to a Word document.. Since the action takes a little longer to execute, I want to show a spinner/busy indicator to the user so he knows there is something happening on the click. However I cannot get the spinner to stop once the dialog pops asking the user to Save/Cancel. I cannot use ajax calls either to export the stuff since the dialog box asking the user to save/cancel doesn't even show if using ajax calls.
I have done this before using jQuery/Ajax calls (hiding the spinner on success etc..) but now the scenario includes showing dialog to save or cancel the exported file. Any thoughts here?!
Below is the code I have..

```
<a id="Export" class="btn btn-warning" href="@Url.Action("ExportToWord", "Export")"> Export to Word </a>
```

```js
        $('body').on('click', '#Export', function(e) {

            $('#loading').show();

            @*/*----if using ajax: spinner loads and hides but dialog box doesn't show up-------*/
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ExportToWord", "Export")',
                cache: false,
                data: { customerId: custId, solutionId: solId },
                success: function(result) {

                    window.open(result); // doesn't work

                    $('body').find('#loading').hide();

                },
                error: function(r) {

                }
            });*@

        });
```

Comment: use the progress: event to display your spinner and the complete: event to hide your spinner.

Comment: Tried and it didn't work unfortunately. The spinner wouldn't show up and the dialog box also wouldn't popup!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?